# Is it correct to state that calling virtual method through child doesn't use vtable?

Tags: c++, virtual, vtable

Let say I've [this](https://godbolt.org/z/v4K8c9rvE) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct Base
{
    virtual float getValue() { return 1.0f; }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    float getValue() override { return 2.0f; }
};

inline void test(Base *obj) {
    std::cout << obj->getValue() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    test(&d);
    float value = d.getValue();
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

I would say that most of the time, `test(&d);` is processed at runtime using vtable.

But what I looking for is how `float value = d.getValue();` its compiled; since its know at "compile time", directly from the object which point to the target function, is it correct to state that this will never use vtable? (basically, its the same method called if it wasn't decleared virtual).

Comment: C++ by itself has no such thing as vtable. It's just one possible way to implement virtual functions. Thus, it's impossible to argue in general - you can only check if your particular compiler implements optimisation to resolve the function call in compile time. For example, gcc optimises away entire function call even at `O1`: https://godbolt.org/z/5Ko55bsee

Comment: Never say never. __Some compilers__ with __some configurations__ might devirtualize this call.

Comment: In C and C++ there is as-if rule. Meaning compiler has right to alter code in any way as long as all visible effects of this code remain unchanged. So if otpimalizations are enabled and compiler is able to determine exact type of object, then it can invoke virtual member function directly without dynamic lookup (vtable). This is your case.

Comment: @MarekR: also in this case? https://godbolt.org/z/6hq8j4P8Y where it call a overridden virtual function within a non-overridden virtual?

Comment: I'm not compiler writer so I can't tell you what are exact limitation of optimizations. I'm just pointing out that compiler has right to do such optimizations.

Comment: @MarekR There is no rule in either C or C++ called the as if rule. It's just an observation, a way to explain stuff. But saying it's a "rule" (like the rules on operators, on type declarations, on namespaces...) causes endless confusion.

Comment: @curiousguy https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if https://eel.is/c++draft/intro#footnote-6

Comment: @MarekR "The semantic descriptions in this document define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine" Do you know of any "PL semantics" that does not do that? Can you even imagine one? Do you know a way to define PL by any mean that does not end up with an "abstract machine"? Can you make up an alternate C++ in an alternate universe that does not have such property? Can you sort out (in the discussions of C++ programs, or C programs, or Java programs) those that rely on the as-if rule and those that don't?